# Windows Task Scheduler Misbehaving with Queue Instance

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have created a task on Windows 7 (64 Bit) Task Scheduler with time-based launch of script to launch at 20th minute of every hour. 
On the setting tab, have enabled "Queue a new instance" if the task is already running.

With this options enable, I am seeing en errored start of two instances being triggered at the same time as given below.

i.e There are no instances running actually and the previous instance ended long before the current trigger time.

Does anyone else come across such situations or know whats causing this?

[image]